# Get all the Document set title in the library using REST API in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, document-set

How to get the title of all the Document sets in the Library using REST API in SharePoint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/180585/fetch-sharepoint-document-set-all-files-and-fields. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the above link. in above link from documentset getting the details of the files. But My requirements is get all the documentsets title using RESTAPI

Comment: Try answer given below.

Answer (score 2):

Use REST endpoint like below:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentSets')/items?$select=Title
```

Where `DocumentSets` is the name of your document library.

**Library**:

[image]

**REST API Response**:

```
<entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Title>My Document Set</d:Title>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
<entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Title>Document Set 1</d:Title>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
<entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Title>REST API Document Set</d:Title>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

**Update**:

If you want to get only document sets from document library, you can filter based on content type like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentSets')/items?$select=Title&$filter=ContentType eq 'Document Set'
```

Where `Document Set` is the name of your content type:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I am having folders, Files and Documentsets in the Library. I need only DOcumentsets.

Comment: check updated answer.

Comment: Thnaks Ganesh, It is working for me.Thanks for quick help

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you

Comment: Hi @user3771062, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.